# How to get last modify timestamp in IBM Domino notes?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, lotus-notes

I have a problem that I need sync data between domino and mysql. Now I cannot find which field show me a document's last modified timestamp in domino notes database, therefore I cannot sure if that document data need sync.
Please help me.

Comment: You should add your current efforts to solve the problem to the question. What code did you try? Where are your problems? Maybe a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be of help here. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no field for the "last modified timestamp" in an IBM Notes document (unless you create one). But there is a property.

`notesDocument.LastModified` for [lotusscript](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_LASTMODIFIED_PROPERTY_DOC.html) or

`@Modified` in [Formula](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_MODIFIED.html)